# costum loss : check max and min values of variable of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I wrote a costum loss function in tensorflow. But sth is going wrong, because the error is larger 1 which shouldnt be possible. So I want to look up the values of y_predicted and y_true as well as the new calulated loss. but I don't know how to get acces to these values. y_pred and y_true are both of the type `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'`

this is my costum loss fct:

```
def square_loss_invalid_pixel(y_true,y_pred):
   print("type ",type(y_true),type(y_pred))
   print("y_true: ", y_true)
   print("max:_ ",(tf.reduce_max(y_true)))
   print("min:_ ",(tf.reduce_min(y_pred)))

   loss = square_loss(y_true, y_pred) # (b, h, w)

   print("max:_ ",(tf.reduce_max(loss)))
   print("min:_ ",(tf.reduce_min(loss)))

   loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss)
   return loss
```

and the output is:

```
y_true:  Tensor("IteratorGetNext:2", shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=float32)
max:_  Tensor("square_loss_invalid_pixel/Max:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
min:_  Tensor("square_loss_invalid_pixel/Min:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
max:_  Tensor("square_loss_invalid_pixel/Max_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
min:_  Tensor("square_loss_invalid_pixel/Min_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

As you can see I don't get much information out of it. Do you know how tho get the right values.
I have batches of size 8 . And I get my input from a generator fct.

Thanks in advance!
Best regards

Comment: try using `tf.print` instead of `print`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by compiling the model with `run_eagerly=True` :

`model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=square_loss_costum, run_eagerly=True)`